# Why import .m file?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a source file, well actually it is a Google API library.

It has this code on `GTLCommon_Sources.m`:

```
#if defined(__has_feature) && __has_feature(objc_arc)
#error "This file needs to be compiled with ARC disabled."
#endif

#import "Objects/GTLBatchQuery.m"
#import "Objects/GTLBatchResult.m"
#import "Objects/GTLDateTime.m"
#import "Objects/GTLErrorObject.m"
#import "Objects/GTLObject.m"
#import "Objects/GTLQuery.m"
#import "Objects/GTLRuntimeCommon.m"
#import "Objects/GTLService.m"
#import "Objects/GTLUploadParameters.m"

#import "Utilities/GTLBase64.m"
#import "Utilities/GTLFramework.m"
#import "Utilities/GTLJSONParser.m"
#import "Utilities/GTLUtilities.m"
```

However, try to build it, results on duplicate symbols on `GTLCommon_Sources` and `GTLJSONParser`. I tried change the source file to `#import "Utilities/GTLJSONParser.h"` instead of `#import "Utilities/GTLJSONParser.m"` and the duplicate symbols error goes away.

Can anyone advise why this library imports a .m file? While AFAIK, we always import .h file.

Comment: Did you search in your project that you have only one copy of these two files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a convenient way to build all the source files without having all of them included in your project. See [the documentation](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary#compiling-the-source-files-directly-into-a-mac-or-ios-application).

> Rather than link to the GTL framework, you can compile the GTL library
>   sources directly into your own project. To do this, find the library's
>   GTLCommon_Sources.m and GTLCommon_Networking.m files, and drag the
>   files into your project's window.
>
> Then add the library's source folders to the Header Search Paths entry
>   of your project's build settings: Source, Source/Objects,
>   Source/Utilities, Deps/gtm-session-fetcher/Source,
>   Deps/gtm-oauth2/Source, Deps/gtm-oauth2/Source/Touch (or
>   Deps/gtm-oauth2/Source/Mac).

For that to work, do **not** add any other of the other sources (`GTLBatchQuery.m`, etc.) to your project.

Comment: Thanks zpasternack! However I found another issue, if you may help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37563249/google-api-gtmoauth2viewcontrollertouch-not-found :)