# Google Api _GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch not found

Tags: ios, xcode, youtube-data-api

I am trying to integrate with Youtube Data API. I have put these libraries inside my project folder:

```
google-api-objectivec-client-read-only
```

and, inside of folder: google-api-objectivec-client-read-only

```
gtm-http-fetcher
gtm-oauth2
gtm-session
```

inside `google-api-objectivec-client-read-only`. However, during build:

```
(null): "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch", referenced from:
```

How can I take above error away?

Here is my `Header Search Path`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this link will help you out

https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/issues/165

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to be able build my project based on answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34857833/quick-start-instructions-for-gmail-api-on-xcode-7-do-not-work/34969420#34969420).

I get the files from [here](https://github.com/google/gtm-oauth2).

Added following .h and .m files to my project and disable their ARC `-fno-objc-arc`:

```
GTMOAuth2Authentication
GTMOAuth2SignIn
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch (also with XIB file)
```